# Function working except when you click it first time, Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have created a JavaScript `onclick` function. It works fine in Firefox. but in Chrome/IE, function working except when you click it first time. My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

function KeepCount() {
  
  var mytextbox = document.getElementById('onclickval1');
  var myform = document.getElementById('compare-meet');
  var inputElems = myform.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {
    inputElems[i].onchange = function(){
        if(this.checked){
            
            mytextbox.value += this.value +",";
            s = document.getElementById("onclickval1").value;
            n = s.split(',').length;
            if (n > 5)
            {
                alert('Pick Just Four Please!')
                this.checked = false
                mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(this.value+",", "")
                document.comparepage; return false;
            }
            if (n < 3)
            {
                document.getElementById('compsend').disabled=true;
            }
            if (n > 2)
            {
                document.getElementById('compsend').disabled=false;
            }
        }else{
            mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(this.value+",", "");
            s = document.getElementById("onclickval1").value;
            n = s.split(',').length; 
            if (n < 3)
            {
                document.getElementById('compsend').disabled=true;
            }
            if (n > 2)
            {
                document.getElementById('compsend').disabled=false;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="compare-meet" action="" name="comparepage" method="post">
<input id="onclickval1" type="text" value="" name="getval1" size="30">
<table id="datatable-1" class="views-table">
    <thead>
    <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="
                  ">
          <span id="compbutt"><input id="compsend" title="Select atleast 2 school to compare" disabled="" type="submit" value="Compare &amp; Meet" name="compare"></span>        </th></tr>
  </thead>
  
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"><tr class="views-row-first odd">
                  <td class="">
            <input onclick="KeepCount()" class="5353" id="compare" type="checkbox"  value="5353">          </td>
              </tr><tr class="even">
                  <td class="">
            <input onclick="KeepCount()" class="5357" id="compare" type="checkbox"  value="5357">          </td>
              </tr><tr class="odd">
                  <td class="">
            <input onclick="KeepCount()" class="5533" id="compare" type="checkbox"  value="5533">          </td>
              </tr><tr class="even">
                  <td class="">
            <input onclick="KeepCount()" class="5793" id="compare" type="checkbox"  value="5793">          </td>
              </tr><tr class="odd">
                  <td class="">
            <input onclick="KeepCount()" class="5563" id="compare" type="checkbox"  value="5563">          </td>
              </tr></tbody></table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keepCount()` method is used to register a on change event handler, so you need to execute it on document load, not on click of the input element.

So what happens is when the first click happens there is no `onchange` event handler registered, so it will not get fired, and it registers a onchange event then.
When the second click happens you have a onchange event handler registered so it gets fired
The problem with this is as you keep executing `KeepCount` method the every click will make the `onchange` habdler to fire multiple times

Ex:

```
function KeepCount() {

    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('onclickval1');
    var myform = document.getElementById('compare-meet');
    var inputElems = myform.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {
        inputElems[i].onchange = function(){
            if(this.checked){

                mytextbox.value += this.value +",";
                s = document.getElementById("onclickval1").value;
                n = s.split(',').length;
                if (n > 5)
                {
                    alert('Pick Just Four Please!')
                    this.checked = false
                    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(this.value+",", "")
                    document.comparepage; return false;
                }
                if (n < 3)
                {
                    document.getElementById('compsend').disabled=true;
                }
                if (n > 2)
                {
                    document.getElementById('compsend').disabled=false;
                }
            }else{
                mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(this.value+",", "");
                s = document.getElementById("onclickval1").value;
                n = s.split(',').length; 
                if (n < 3)
                {
                    document.getElementById('compsend').disabled=true;
                }
                if (n > 2)
                {
                    document.getElementById('compsend').disabled=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = KeepCount;
```

And remove the `onclick="KeepCount()"` from the checkboxes

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5pqTt/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<form id="compare-meet" action="" name="comparepage" method="post">
<input id="onclickval1" type="text" value="" name="getval1" size="30">
<table id="datatable-1" class="views-table">
    <thead>
    <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="
                  ">
          <span id="compbutt"><input id="compsend" title="Select atleast 2 school to compare" disabled="" type="submit" value="Compare &amp; Meet" name="compare"></span>        </th></tr>
  </thead>

<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"><tr class="views-row-first odd">
                  <td class="">
            <input class="5353" id="compare" type="checkbox"  value="5353">          </td>
              </tr><tr class="even">
                  <td class="">
            <input class="5357" id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox"  value="5357">          </td>
              </tr><tr class="odd">
                  <td class="">
            <input  class="5533" id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox"  value="5533">          </td>
              </tr><tr class="even">
                  <td class="">
            <input class="5793" id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox"  value="5793">          </td>
              </tr><tr class="odd">
                  <td class="">
            <input class="5563" id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox"  value="5563">          </td>
              </tr></tbody></table>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    function KeepCount() {
        var mytextbox = document.getElementById('onclickval1');
        var myform = document.getElementById('compare-meet');
        var inputElems = myform.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
            inputElems[i].onchange = function () {
                if (this.checked) {

                    mytextbox.value += this.value + ",";
                    s = document.getElementById("onclickval1").value;
                    n = s.split(',').length;
                    if (n > 5) {
                        alert('Pick Just Four Please!')
                        this.checked = false
                        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(this.value + ",", "")
                        document.comparepage; return false;
                    }
                    if (n < 3) {
                        document.getElementById('compsend').disabled = true;
                    }
                    if (n > 2) {
                        document.getElementById('compsend').disabled = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(this.value + ",", "");
                    s = document.getElementById("onclickval1").value;
                    n = s.split(',').length;
                    if (n < 3) {
                        document.getElementById('compsend').disabled = true;
                    }
                    if (n > 2) {
                        document.getElementById('compsend').disabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    KeepCount();
</script>
</html>
```